# Построить матрицу смежности, если даны ребра

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Здравствуйте. Дан массив связей между вершинами (Tuple<string, string>[]). Мне нужно наиболее эффективно построить матрицу смежности по этому массиву. Пока есть один вариант - Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>. Но если учесть, что связей может быть десятки и сотни тысяч, то получается, что это далеко не самый рациональный способ. Так вот, есть ли более эффективный способ построения матрицы смежности?

Comment: а что вы вообще храните в строках, лежащих в кортежах?  Как-то странно, что данные графа хранятся в виде строк (а речь, очевидно, идет о графе, раз вы говорите о матрице смежности). и вообще, к чему эти дурно пахнущие велосипеды со словарями словарей? Раз уж речь о матрице, то почему бы не использовать именно двумерный массив, то есть матрицу?

Comment: Почитайте в гугле про sparse matrix (например, в Кнуте). Идея в том, чтобы хранить не все элементы, а только те, которые интересны. Например, связный список строк, в каждой строке связный список элементов. Или просто `HashSet<Pair<int, int>>`.

Comment: Просто дано такое задание. Мне нужно найти циклические зависимости между некоторыми элементами (например, ["One", "Two"], ["Two", "Three"], ["Three", "One"] - цикл, а ["One", "Two"], ["Two", "Three"] - все нормально). А такое лучше решать с помощью графов, насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @VladD, не особо понял, кок это поможет мне построить граф?

Comment: @devnikor: не, такое лучше всего делать при помощи топологической сортировки.

Comment: @VladD, то есть, мне не нужно строить матрицу смежности, а найти все вершины, и потом применить этот алгоритм?

Comment: @devnikor: Вам в принципе не нужно находить все вершины заранее. Просто если появится ещё не известная вершина, выделите её в отдельный кластер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если string'и - это "названия" вершин, то сделайте один Dictionary<string, int> и храните в нём соответствие название-номер. А матрицу смежности - например, в виде двумерного массива int'ов